# Vim search and replace query

Tags: regex, vim

I have a regular expression like this:

```
:%s/pattern/        pattern/gc
```

As you can see in the replacement text I want eight whitespace characters initially. I don't want to type eight white spaces every time. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're after conserving keystrokes, you can initialize a named register with the replacement text:

```
:let @a = repeat(' ', 8)
```

Then, when building your substitution command, you insert the register contents via CTRL-R + {register-name}:

```
:%s/pattern/<C-R>a&/gc
```

For further simplification, I have referred to the search pattern in the replacement string via `&`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a reasonable solution to me. I can put the register initialization code in .vimrc. I need this because I need to use 8 space indentation in my code.

Comment: I had suspected this, though I would prefer to solve this via `%g/pattern/>` instead of a substitution. PS: Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: @RakRaks Did you mean you need to use 8-space indentation throughout your code, and not just for an occasional 8-space indent?  If so, there are much better ways to get vim to help you.

Comment: @David I have some of that stuff in my .vimrc. But, this is when I copy paste some things and then edit to get the code

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf('%*s', 8, '')`:

> A field width or precision, or both, may be indicated by an `asterisk '*'` instead of a digit string.  In this case, a Number argument supplies the field width.

```
:%s/pattern/\=printf('%*spattern', 8, '')/gc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can repeat some vi commands by entering a numberbefore the command, for example:
8iA
would insert 8 A's (so replace that with space).